# Erro ao instalar o nodemon de forma global

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

Estou com o seguinte problema ao executar este comando:

`npm install -g nodemon@1.18.4 --save-dev --save-exact`

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia Raiany, td bem ? Aparentemente é um problema de permissão, basicamente você não tem permissão para acessar esses diretórios,  tente executar o comando dessa forma: sudo npm install -g nodemon@1.18.4 --save-dev --save-exact

Comment: `sudo npm install -g nodemon@1.18.4 --save-dev --save-exact`. Leia [SUDO: O que é “sudo su” no Linux?](https://4fasters.com.br/2019/01/30/sudo-o-que-e-sudo-su-no-linux/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar o "SUDO", isto se trata de erro de permissão de acesso

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon@1.18.4 --save-dev --save-exact
```

Answer (score 2):

Evite rodar comandos `npm` com sudo. Pode parecer a solução mais fácil, mas abre brecha para scripts maliciosos serem executados na sua máquina. [Este artigo](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92) fala um pouco sobre o assunto.

### Solução recomendada

A solução **recomendada oficialmente** [pelo npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) é reinstalar o npm usando o *node version manager*. A instalação é bem simples e explicada no [repositório oficial do projeto](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

### Solução alternativa

Caso usar `nvm` não seja uma opção, a outra recomendação é alterar manualmente o diretório do npm:

- Faça backup da sua máquina
- Na linha de comando, estando no diretório `home`, crie um diretório para instalar pacotes globais: 
  `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
- Configure o npm para usar este novo diretório: `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
- Adicione este novo diretório ao `PATH`: Crie ou abra o arquivo `~/.profile` e adicione esta linha: `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
- Reinicie o terminal ou rode `source ~/.profile` para atualizar as variáveis de ambiente
- Teste a nova configuração instalando o pacote globalmente sem sudo: `npm install -g nodemon@1.18.4 --save-dev --save-exact`

### Melhor ainda

Se você estiver usando o npm 5.2 ou maior, é possível usar o [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) como alternativa a pacotes globais. [Este artigo](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b) fala mais sobre o assunto.